# Compiling from command line doesn't use libraries

Tags: java, class, jar, compilation, manifest

I'm working on a project where I need to compile .java files 'automaticly'(So not using Eclipse)
And now I have some trouble with the libraries that are required by the sources that I compile.

The problem is that the compiled code extends a class which is inside a library.
I've added classpaths, and made sure the libraries where actually in the correct directory.
But it doesn't seem to be able to run.

I get an error which says that the class can not be found or loaded.
I modified the test source so that it doesn't extend. And then it does work.

How do I make the compiled class be able to actually use the classes from libraries in the class path?

I use this to compile:

```
javac -d /bin -cp kit.jar src/com/indieveloper/kittest/*.java
```

The class files compile with no error, and also in the correct package hierarchy

This is the manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .;lib/kit.jar
Created-By: Me
Main-Class: com.indieveloper.kittest.Main
```

The folder lib with the jar is in the same folder where the final packed .jar also ends up
Which I build using this code:

```
jar cvfm test.jar manifest.txt -C bin/ .
```

The inside of the final jar seems okay to me:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/indieveloper/
com/indieveloper/kittest/
com/indieveloper/kittest/Main.class
```

The manifest is still correct(Nothing changed the manifest during 'jarring')
I also tried putting the lib folder with the jar inside the final jar, but that was a hopeless attempt..

The exact error:

```
java -jar test.jar
   Error: Could not find or load main class com.indieveloper.kittest.Main
```

Does anyone know I can do to make it work?

Comment: Don't do this by hand. Use Maven or Gradle, which will take care of all of these issues.

Comment: But if I were to do it by hand(Well, automated from inside my tool), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Source for `Main.java`? Is that the *entire* error output?

Comment: That is the entire error yes. It's not the source. At least, as I said, it all ran fine when no libraries were used. Once I used something from a library, it started giving the error. Which means the libraries are not accesible by the code, but I don't know why.

Comment: I would expect to see more of an error, specifically a linker error. Try `java -cp kit.jar -jar test.jar` and see if that works. I think you're trying to tell Java that `kit.jar` is included in the jar without actually including the file.

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Does Main.java (upper case Main) have method main (lower case?)